# Exlcuded views field doesn't take override template

Tags: views, entities, theming

Let's say I have a view with 4 fields: Title, Subtitle, Link and Body.
Due to some html output personalization, I excluded the first three fields and added them in the Body field.
For the link content, I previously created an override `views-view-field--view-node.tpl.php` that actually works in other situations (with other views).
In this case, however, the Link field doesn't display as in the tpl but as the default template (I.e. in my tpl I added some classes to the  tag).
Anyone experienced this and solved?

Comment: I also need this -- did you ever solve?

Comment: Actually, no. Maybe we can open an issue in drupal.org ?

Comment: I suppose. I wanted to add a class to an Anchor Tag, and I ended up wrapping the anchor tag in a span tag and theming a span.myclass>a.myclass as a workaround.